# Do grad schools let you know whether you get a place and funding at the same time?

Tags: phd

I know that there are often two processes after a PhD interview: the school will decide whether (1) you get a place; (2) whether you get funding. From your experience, did you hear back from your potential supervisors first whether you get a place or did you get to know both at the same time? It's been almost three weeks since my interview and I haven't heard anything from the school (I applied for a UK university and the school of Arts and Humanities, and the funding body is the university, which offers scholarships for several schools and departments). The chair of the interview did say to me that the first process will be quick and the second will take 4-8 weeks. Does this mean I won't be offered a place?

Comment: The decisions may be joined or not. This varies by place. Normally you will be told either way. You will likely hear early if you are not successful and later if you are.

Comment: When I chaired my department's graduate admissions committee (about 20 years ago), applicants were informed of admission and funding simultaneously. (Except in very unusual cases, we offered funding to everyone we admitted. Most of the funding was in the form of teaching assistantships.) As far as I know, this situation has not changed since then.

Comment: I suspect this varies quite a bit based on discipline, school, and country.  I certainly have had students admitted without aid (at the time of acceptance, usually eventually getting aid) to PhD programs in the same discipline as @AndreasBlass - though less prestigious institutions which probably could not decide on how many TA positions they would have for the next year that early; I'm sure his answer is still true for similar institutions to his in our field today.

Comment: I will give a more constructive comment that perhaps you can modify your question to be about "in which disciplines/countries/types of institutions are these two decisions typically closely connected, and in which are they not", in which case it will be much more helpful to those finding it later.  I think that people who have been around a while in discipline X in country Y can make fairly accurate answers to that.

Comment: I am not an expert, but I assume that means the decisions are independent.  If unfunded study is not acceptable to you then I would not even apply to such schools.

Comment: I did, but it wasn't technically finalized until I accepted, at which point I received the final package (which included first-summer funding, which wasn't technically on my offer).

Comment: In the US you'd expect to hear about both simultaneously, but at least at some place in the UK I think things are potentially more complicated.   For example acceptance to the program could be decided by the department with funding coming (at least in part) from a college, etc.